# How do I create a new photo album for a page, through the facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've tried:

```
POST:
[page id]/albums/?name="test"
```

on

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

with

```
user_photos, friend_photos, manage_pages
```

permissions. I see this response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Invalid ID for album owner", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

which is clearly not what I expected. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I'm following the pattern I've used for programmatically creating user albums - and which, I've been led to expect, would also work for pages

Comment: Do you have a page access token? There are several page operations that cannot be done with a page admin's user access token.

Comment: See this question, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447111/error-in-my-code-or-facebook-bug - now, once I created the album, I can't seem to access it properly.